# Typing “$” command does not jump to the end of line [cursor set to “|” (bar/pipe) rather than block shape]

Tags: c++, vim

I install YCM(You complete me), and when I coding, I found the command $ is not work right. It doesn't jump to the end of line, but the last one . For exampl, a line in a.cpp:

```cpp
#include| <sys/socket.h>
```

now the cursor is after the **include**, then I type $, try jump to the end of line, but I get the following as a result:

```cpp
#include <sys/socket.h|>
```

How can I do to make it work right?

Comment: What commands, *exactly*? In what mode? Etc.

Comment: normal mode, just type **shift+4** ('$' actually)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your cursor shape is causing some confusion.

In normal mode, the cursor is *on* a character, not *between* two characters, which is pretty clear and obvious if your cursor shape is a "block":

[image: block]

With a "vertical bar" shape, the bar has to be on one side or the other of the character, usually the left side:

[image: bar]

In both cases, the cursor actually ends up on the same character—the `>`, as expected—but the "bar" cursor shape makes it harder than necessary to reason about the current cursor position.

If that's indeed the cause of the confusion, I would suggest setting your cursor shape to a "block", which makes a lot more sense in Vim.

Answer (score 5):

That is what `$` does, it jumps **onto** the last character on the line. Then you can either press `i` to insert text before this last character or `a` to insert after.

I would recommend to have block cursor enabled in your terminal, it makes `a`,`i` more clear. At least for me.

It should not have anything to do with YCM or other plugins.